# 3001: Invalid Argument - Required Fields

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working on an Access database that I'd like to gain more control over when a record is saved. One of the things I'd like to do is check that all required fields on whatever form is calling my SaveResponse function have been filled in. Here's the relevant bits of code I've come up with.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    SaveResponse(Form.Recordset)
End Sub

Public Function SaveResponse(rs As Recordset) As Long
    Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult, fld As Field    
    response = MsgBox("Do you want to save changes to this record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Save Record")

    If response = vbYes Then
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            If fld.Required = True And Nz(fld, "") = "" Then
                MsgBox "The " & fld.Name & " field is required."
                SaveResponse = 2
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf response = vbNo Then
        CodeContextObject.Undo
        SaveResponse = 1
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

When running, I get an error: "3001: Invalid Argument"

I think I've narrowed this issue down to where I am actually checking if a given field in the record set is null (the code below).

```
Nz(fld, "") = ""
```

I've tried the following alternatives with no luck...

```
Nz(fld.Value, "") = ""

Nz(rs.Fields(fld.Name).Value, "") = ""

IsNull(fld.Value)

IsNull(rs.Fields(fld.Name).Value)
```

What am I missing? How can I check required fields in the record set for null values?

**Edit:** New code below addresses new records not yet in the recordset, but returns "3265 Item not found in this collection."

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    SaveResponse(Form)
End Sub

Public Function SaveResponse(frm as Form) As Long
    Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult, rs as Recordset, ctl As Control, fldName As String   
    response = MsgBox("Do you want to save changes to this record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Save Record")

    If response = vbYes Then
        Set rs = frm.Recordset
        For Each ctl In frm.Controls
            fldName = ctl.ControlSource
            If rs(fldName).Required And Nz(fldName, "") = "" Then
                MsgBox "The " & fldName & " field is required."
                SaveResponse = 2
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf response = vbNo Then
        CodeContextObject.Undo
        SaveResponse = 1
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

This time, I believe the issue is with the line `If rs(fldName).Required`. Any ideas?

Comment: `Nz(fld, "") = ""`  should work. Code seems to be okay.

Comment: @Santosh Just tried it again and unfortunately, it returns the same error: 3001 Invalid Argument.

Comment: Does it error on first iteration of loop?

Comment: I am testing your code and I get Type Mismatch error on the SaveResponse function in the BeforeUpdate event.

Comment: I don't see how this code will ever do what you want. What if the form's recordset is 5,000 records? Also, a new record not yet committed to table is not in the form's Recordset. Could set fields as required in table and let Access nag users. Can also use ValidationRule and ValidationText properties. Users will eventually learn to avoid these annoyances.

Comment: I have tested and this code works. Does it get stuck at any specific control? Can you add screenshot of the UI.

Comment: @June7 Try this `Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    SaveResponse rs
End Sub` to call SaveResponse function from the event.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't error. Code runs when I enter new record, however, the record from recordset that code looks at is first record in form's recordset, not new record. I already confirmed new record is not yet in the recordset. I used rs.MoveLast and Debug.Print to verify.

Comment: when Error 3001 appears, does it highlights line `Nz(fld.Value, "") = ""` ??? Anyways, have you tried using [IsNull function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnull-function)?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes, I tried replacing with IsNull.

Comment: @Santosh It gets stuck at the first required field that is blank. I've added new code to the question though. Have a look!

Comment: @June7 I've added code (see edit to question) to address your point regarding new records not yet being a part of the recordset. I'm getting a different error now. Any ideas?

Comment: Won't work if controls are on a subform. Can't pass a subform as a Form object. Code loops through ALL controls, some of which won't have ControlSource property and therefore code fails - labels for instance are not data controls. One way to deal with is to use Tag property. Use some string in Tag, such as "Validate", then in code test Tag property for that string and if match, run validation.